# C# ASP.Net Core - Passing Currently logged on Username to API

Tags: security, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, windows-identity

I want to pick up the user that is currently logged on to my web site, in an API on a different site. I do not want to pass the Username via a parameter for security reasons.

In my REST API I have code like this:

```
var userName = Environment.UserName;
```

This API is called from a WebSite that makes use of the same code.

On my local machine, with both the site and the API running, I pick up the currently logged on user in both the site and the API. (With windows Authentication turned on and Anonymous off, on both the Site and the API, I get an Authentication Failure: 401 when I call my API)

When I deploy the site to AzureWebSites, I do not get my Username populated on the API, but it does work in my web site.

What do I need to do to get the username pushed through to the API?

The code (C#) I'm using to call the API from my web site looks like this:

```
    private async Task<List<ResultSet>> GetResults()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        List<ResultSet> Results = null;

        var url = string.Format("{0}/api/Answer", APIUri);

        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
        authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(QuestionsURL, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
              Results = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ResultSet>>();
        }
        return Results;
    }
```

The `accessToken` comes through just fine and the api works for other endpoints that do not make use of `Environment.Username`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured the authentication middleware properly, you should be able to get the username from the User principal object. User object gets populated by the access token passed to the API. I see you have Azure AD as identity provider. You can use [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg) GitHub example to set your API up.